# Firebase: How do I register my Flutter app in app check?

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-app-check

I want to register my `Flutter` app in `Firebase` app check. When I try to register, it keeps asking me to upload the **private key** which should be in `P8` format.

How do I get this private key? I have created an *apple developer account*, but I don't know how to proceed after that. Can someone please guide me?

Also how do I get the **Key ID** and the **Team ID**?

[image: I am stuck here]

Answer (score 0):

FOLLOW THESE STEPS

- Login into your apple developer account.
- Click certificate.
- Click on keys.
- Enter key name. ( anything you like )
- Create key and check 'Apple Push Notifications service (APNs)'.
- Click 'Continue' and download certificate.
- Click on certificate listing and select that key name.
- Copy 'Key Id'.
- Top right corner is your 'Team Id'.
- The certificate you download before is your p8 certificate.

:)

Comment: It says that I have to enroll into the apple development program. And to enroll I have to install the apple devloper app, but unfortunately I don't have any Apple devices.

Comment: oh!. Yes you have to enroll first from device or install app developer in your mac also. You can also enroll it from mac.

Comment: Well that's the thing, I don't have mac or any apple devices. Is there a way to bypass this?

Answer (score 0):

[apple Developer account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iqm0H.png)

1. You can get it from apple developer account
   https://developer.apple.com/
2. Then Certificates,
3. Then Keys tabs
4. Create New Key and select Apple Push Notifications service (APNs)

Comment: This is a duplicate of another answer for this question. Make sure you read the other answers posted to make sure you are not repeating the same solution.